NixOS fails to boot after install in dual boot
After installing NixOS via usb, in a separate partition of 80 GB, I boot through GRUB and get the following log:
:: running early hook [udev]
Starting systemd-udevd version 255.3-1-arch
:: running hook [udev]
:: Triggering uevents
:: running hook [keymap]
:: Loading keymap...done.
:: performing fsck on '/dev/nvme0n1p3'
/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean, 403506/5120000 files, 2715735/20480000 blocks
********************** WARNING **********************
*                                                   *
*  The root device is not configured to be mounted  *
*  read-write! It may be fsck'd again later         *
*                                                   *
*****************************************************
:: mounting '/dev/nvme0n1p3' on real root
:: running cleanup hook [udev]
ERROR: Root device mounted successfully, but /sbin/init does not exist.
Bailing out, you are on your own. Good luck.

sh: can't access tty: job control turned off

It then gives me a prompt which in which I can type but most command won't work, and to shut down I have to force shutdown the computer.
Searching on here I found that this error may be caused by using GRUB as the bootloader while the default GUI installation uses systemd-boot. I then configured manually the config file after the GUI installation in order to implement GRUB as per specified by the manual, but the error persisted. How can I get my NixOS to boot properly? (I just need a working terminal as I want to install hyprland which already requires a custom install as there isn't the hyprland option in the GUI installer)
